# AVL Tree and segmentation fault

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I'm trying to do an AVL tree and got the segmentation fault. After doing some research on here, I know im trying to access memory that i don't have access for. Problem is I couldn't figure out where I did wrong.

I tried to debug and the command prompt say

> Warning : GDB : Failed to set controlling terminal : operation not permitted

here is my header file

```
#ifndef AVLTREE_H_
#define AVLTREE_H_

#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
static const int ALLOWED_IMBALANCE = 1;
template<class T>
class AVLNode {
public:
    // Default blank AVLNode constructor
    AVLNode() {
        left = right = nullptr;
        height = 0;
    }

    // Constructor with provided element (data) and children
    AVLNode(const T& el, AVLNode *l = nullptr, AVLNode *r = nullptr) {
        key = el;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        height = 0;
    }

    T key;                  // Key to compare/insert on of type <T>
    AVLNode *left, *right;  // Children of this node
    int height;             // Height of this node in the tree
};

template<class T>
class AVLTree {
  public:

    AVLTree() { root = nullptr; }

    void insert(const T& key) { insert(root, key); }

    void printTree() { printTree(root); }

    bool contains( const T& key ){ return(contains(root, key)); }

    void remove( const T& key ){ remove(root, key); }

    int Height(AVLNode<T> * &key) {
    return key == nullptr ? -1:key->height;}

    void balance(const T& key);



  private:
    AVLNode<T>* root;

    AVLNode<T> *findMin(AVLNode<T>* &node){
          if (node !=nullptr){
             while( node->left !=nullptr){
                node = node->left;
              }
            }
       return node;
    }

     void  rightRotation(AVLNode<T>* &node) {
        AVLNode<T>* left = node->left;

       node->left = left->right;
       left->right = node;
       node = left;
    }


      void leftRotation(AVLNode<T>* &node) {
         AVLNode<T>* right = node->right;

         node->right = right->left;
         right->left = node;
         node = right;
       }



     void insert(AVLNode<T>* &node, const T& key) {
         if(node == nullptr) {
            node = new AVLNode<T> (key);
          }
         else if(key > node->key) {
            insert(node->right, key);
          }
         else {
            insert(node->left, key);
          }
      balance( node);
     } 


   void   balance(AVLNode<T> * &node){
    if (node == nullptr){
        return;}

    if (Height(node->left) - Height(node->right) > ALLOWED_IMBALANCE )                   {
        if(Height (node->left->left) >= Height(node->left->right)){
            rightRotation(node);
        }
        else{
           leftRotation(node);}

    }

    else{
        if (Height(node->right) - Height(node->left) > ALLOWED_IMBALANCE ){
             if(Height (node->right->right) >= Height(node->right->left)){
            leftRotation(node);
        }
        else{
           rightRotation(node);}
        }
    }

    node->height = max( Height(node->left),Height(node->right))+1;
    }




//check contain of the tree
    bool contains(AVLNode<T>* root, const T& key) {


   if (root = nullptr){
   return false;}

   else if ( key < root->key){
    return contains (root, key);

    }

    else if (key > root->key){
    return contains(root, key);
    }

    else
    return true;
    }

    // remove contain of a tree

     void remove( AVLNode<T>* root, const T& key) {

        AVLNode<T> *oldNode = root;
      if ( root == nullptr){
      return;
      }

      if(key < root->key){
            remove(root->left, key);
      }

      else if (key > root->key){
        remove (root->right,key);
      }

      else if( (root->left != nullptr && root->right != nullptr)){
        root->key = findMin( root->right)->key;
        remove(root->right, root->key);
      }

      else{


        root = ( root->left !=nullptr) ? root->left : root->right;
        delete oldNode;
      }

      balance(root);
    }

    // Should do a level order printout with actual depth (no alignment)
     void printTree(AVLNode<T>* node) {
      queue<AVLNode<T>*> bufQueue;
      int curr_height = node->height;
      bufQueue.push(node);
      while( !bufQueue.empty() ) {
        AVLNode<T>* curr = bufQueue.front();
        if( curr->left  != nullptr ){ bufQueue.push(curr->left ); }
        if( curr->right != nullptr ){ bufQueue.push(curr->right); }
        if( curr->height < curr_height ){
          cout << endl;
          curr_height = curr->height;
        }
        cout << curr->key << " ";
        bufQueue.pop();
      }
      cout << endl;
    }


  // end private
};

#endif
```

and main

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <stdlib.h>  // rand
  #include <time.h>    // time for srand
  #include "AVL.h"

int main() {
  AVLTree<int> myTree;

  cout << "Sample series of inserts. Will do all 4 cases of rotates." << endl;
  myTree.insert(20);
  myTree.insert(10);
  myTree.insert(5);
  myTree.insert(30);
  myTree.insert(40);
  myTree.insert(15);
  myTree.insert(18);
  myTree.insert(13);
  myTree.insert(4);
  myTree.insert(19);
  myTree.printTree();

  if( myTree.contains(15) == true){
    cout << "Tree contains 15" << endl;
  }else{
    cout << "Tree does not contain 15" << endl;
  }

  myTree.remove(15);
  if( myTree.contains(15) == true){
    cout << "Tree contains 15" << endl;
  }else{
    cout << "Tree does not contain 15" << endl;
  }


  myTree.printTree();


  return(0);
}
```

Comment: How do you try to run GDB?

Comment: So what is your question, exactly?

Comment: Here are some things to keep you busy: `printTree` can't print an empty tree.`remove` doesn't work at all. `contains` has a serious typo. `findMin` modifies the tree, which is fatal.

Comment: And a debugging tip: Big arbitrary things are very difficult to debug, but it seems that no programming education teaches systematic testing and debugging. Don't be arbitrary. Start with the simplest possible case, the empty tree, and make sure it works. Then test with one node. Then add one node at a time, *systematically*, in ways that will (and will not) cause rebalancing. After every change, make sure that all the previous tests still work. (Write one function per test. Call them from `main`.)